# Font Awesome 5 Star Rating using table

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors, font-awesome

I tried follow this code (https://codepen.io/pezmotion/pen/RQERdm) and convert it using table. But my previous star did not follow when hover every each star.

html

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="rating">
      <td><input id="rating-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5"/><label for="rating-5"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-smile"></i></label></td>
      <td><input id="rating-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" /><label for="rating-4"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-smile"></i></label></td>
      <td><input id="rating-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3"/><label for="rating-3"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-smile"></i></label></td>
      <td><input id="rating-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2"/><label for="rating-2"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-smile"></i></label></td>
      <td><input id="rating-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1"/><label for="rating-1"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-smile"></i></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

css

```
.rating {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    color: #ddd; /* Personal choice */
}
.rating td input {
    display: none;
}
.rating td label:hover,
.rating td label:hover ~ td label,
.rating td input:checked + td label,
.rating td input:checked + td label ~ td label {
    color: #ffc107; /* Personal color choice. Lifted from Bootstrap 4 */
}
```

This is my code. https://codepen.io/ikramsyakir/pen/wvJNyzv

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

(default color without hover is grey, on hover it's yellow for all stars, but overwritten by grey for all stars that follow the hovered one)

```css
.rating {
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
}
.rating input {
    display: none;
}
.rating label {
    color: #ddd; 
}
.rating:hover label {
    color: #ffc107; 
}
.rating label:hover ~ label {
    color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
<div class="rating" style="width: 20rem">
    <input id="rating-5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5"/><label for="rating-5"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-star"></i></label>
    <input id="rating-4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4" checked /><label for="rating-4"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-star"></i></label>
    <input id="rating-3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3"/><label for="rating-3"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-star"></i></label>
    <input id="rating-2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2"/><label for="rating-2"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-star"></i></label>
    <input id="rating-1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1"/><label for="rating-1"><i class="fas fa-3x fa-star"></i></label>
</div>
```

Comment: i see. thanks for ur feedback. but still not working in my table. its seems hover all my star.

Comment: The HTML code is exactly the code of your codepen. In the CSS part, the functionality depends on the order of the CSS rules.

Comment: Yeah i still not sure what i doing, nvm, i keep trying

Answer (score 0):

In a table there's a possibility that you are repeating the id's for the controls. Try generating unique id's and see.